# data-disable-with button option doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3

The following HTML should disable and rename the button accordingly while submitting :

```
  <button data-disable-with="Please wait..." name="button" type="submit">Checkout</button>
```

But in myChrome browser it doesn't do anything.
Anything I can do ?

My Chrome version is 30

Comment: Tags you've listed in the question suggest that you assume some native html behavior. Why your code SHOULD disable and rename the button on submit?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using this in a Rails/Jquery environment

Comment: I found this reference on GitHub that says the problem is pending https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-disable-with` can only be used in rails form element. But if you want to apply it on HTML form elements you can do something like as follows-

You can try `data-loading-text="Loading..."`along with a js code snippet.

```
$("#btn1").on("click", function(){
    $(this).button("loading");
})
```