# Using data-disable-with in a React JSX button element

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, jsx

I have form I'm constructing using React / JSX

When I click submit, I'd like to disable the button with a message (e.g. "Please wait...") so the user can't double-submit.

I'm using `data-disable-with` to accomplish that.

```
<button data-disable-with="Please wait..." onChange={this.foo} className="blah" onClick={this.submit}>
  Submit
</button>
```

However it's not disabling the button when I try it out in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

I know the `data-disable-with` property works because I use it elsewhere in my web framework (Rails + ERB templates) when I'm not using React to generate the form. So my guess is I've incorrectly implemented it here in React.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [data-disable-with button option doesn't work on Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630545/data-disable-with-button-option-doesnt-work-on-chrome)

Comment: Try `<button {...{'data-disable-with': 'Please wait...'}}>`

Comment: @Nick - thanks for the suggestion. Would you mind explaining what the `{...` does here? Thanks!

Comment: @user2490003 https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes